# ObservedObject not receiving changes in variable

Tags: swiftui, observedobject

I've got a Published variable that changes when a function is called. I print the variable within the class and I can see that it has set the variable but when it doesn't change my View, and when I print the variable it's only printing what I initially set the variable at.

I know there have been a couple similar posts on this, but after going through them I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Code is as follows: (minus bits I think aren't relevant here)

Class containing function that is called to change the variable

```
class MusicManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    @Published var playlistLabel: String = "N/A"

    func playPlaylistNow(chosenPlaylist: String?) {
        ...
        playlistLabel = chosenPlaylist!
        print(playlistLabel) // I get the revised variable printed here 
    }
}
```

View to Update

```
struct HomeView: View {

    ...
    @ObservedObject var musicManager: MusicManager = MusicManager()

    var body: some View {
                ...
                SongLabels(trackLabel: currentTrack!, artistLabel: currentArtist!, playlistLabel: musicManager.playlistLabel)
                ...
            }
                ...
            .onAppear {
                self.updateTrackData()
        }
    }

    func updateTrackData() {
        print("Playlist: \(musicManager.playlistLabel)") // I get the original "N/A" printed here
    }
```

View that calls the function:

```
{
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    let musicManager: MusicManager = MusicManager()
    var playlistName: String
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingAlert = true
            self.musicManager.playPlaylistNext(chosenPlaylist: self.playlistName)
        }) {
            Text("Play Next")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where `playPlaylistNow` is called from?

Comment: It's called from a different view called TrackTable. The path is Home View > Button > PlaylistTable > TrackTable

Comment: anybody else changing playlistlabel?

Comment: No. When it's printed in home view it is unchanged, and when it gets passed down to a subview it's not changed either

Answer (score -1):

You have more than one instance of `MusicManager` in your app, so they are not identical.

If you would like to print, you can print both `musicManager` , to see the difference.

Comment: Because I have one instance in the HomeView and one in the View that calls the function? How do I get around that then? I need to call the function from the View which the user selects the music from and then I need to update the label on the HomeView

Comment: You need to use binding somewhere, or environmentObject with the same `MusicManager `.

Comment: I've added the view from which the function is called for above for you to see. I'm really not sure where I should have the binding, the environment object, and the published statement